# Microsoft Teams (beta) API: Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I used the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/graph-explorer) to test against my Office 365 profile. Everything works fine accept the Microsoft Teams (beta) API. If I use GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams I get

> Status Code 401 - Looks like you may not have the permissions for this
>   call. Please modify your permissions.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "a1733d8a-5adb-45ad-a0ad-463595d71a89",
            "date": "2017-06-09T14:33:11"
        }
    }
}
```

There seems no option for give permission for Microsoft Teams. Has anyone figured that out, yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation page for listing your joined teams is at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams.  It looks like this call requires the `User.Read.All` or `User.ReadWrite.All` permissions. To change your permissions in the Graph explorer, you can click `Modify Permissions`

[image]

Then find and enable either permission:

[image]

However, these scopes require tenant administrators to let the Graph Explorer use admin only scopes.  You can either just login as an administrator to just test with that account, or you can let any user in your organization access admin scopes through the explorer by clicking the link that says `grant access to your entire organization`.

[image]

Also, I'm glad you found the Microsoft Teams samples.  We just added these last week and it's great to see developers are trying them out! Thanks for your feedback on the permissions process for the Teams in explorer, I'll pass that along to all the engineers on the project.

Comment: I can't able to change permissions. getting  following error, --   To change permissions, you will need to log-in again. 
You have selected permissions that only an administrator can grant. To get access, an administrator can grant access to your entire organization. -- if you found solution for that can you please revert me back.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a command line tool that lets you bulk create new Microsoft Team channels using the Graph APIs outlined above. It includes instructions on how to register your application for use with your Teams environment - and provide administrative consent so that non-admins can use it.

One of the API calls is to "joinedTeams", which lists the Teams you're currently a member of.  Take a look in "SelectJoinedTeam" function in the ChannelSurfCli/Utils/Channels.cs class.

https://github.com/tamhinsf/ChannelSurf