# Not able to access Microsoft Teams APIs

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am working on POC where I want to access Microsoft Teams API.i.e.
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams

But getting below error details. Error details are as follows.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "ac2efa19-dc29-4573-9ece-ba98b564818e",
            "date": "2018-02-16T12:55:15"
        }
    }
}
```

I have given below permissions from microsoft azure for my registered application.

> Bookings.Manage.All Bookings.Read.All Bookings.ReadWrite.All
>   BookingsAppointment.ReadWrite.All Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.Shared
>   Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared Contacts.Read
>   Contacts.Read.Shared Contacts.ReadWrite Contacts.ReadWrite.Shared
>   Device.Command Device.Read EAS.AccessAsUser.All email Files.Read
>   Files.Read.All Files.Read.Selected Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All
>   Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder Files.ReadWrite.Selected
>   Financials.ReadWrite.All Mail.Read Mail.Read.Shared Mail.ReadWrite
>   Mail.ReadWrite.Shared Mail.Send Mail.Send.Shared MailboxSettings.Read
>   MailboxSettings.ReadWrite Notes.Create Notes.Read Notes.Read.All
>   Notes.ReadWrite Notes.ReadWrite.All Notes.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp
>   offline_access openid People.Read profile Sites.Manage.All
>   Sites.Read.All Sites.ReadWrite.All Tasks.Read Tasks.Read.Shared
>   Tasks.ReadWrite Tasks.ReadWrite.Shared User.Read User.ReadBasic.All
>   User.ReadWrite UserTimelineActivity.Write.CreatedByApp

Above permissions I can see when I decrypt access token.

I have gone through that [Microsoft Teams (beta) API: Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460717/microsoft-teams-beta-api-looks-like-you-may-not-have-the-permissions-for-this) post and already have given permission as per above post but still getiing same error.

Here is screen shot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD7KN.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Teams (beta) API: Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460717/microsoft-teams-beta-api-looks-like-you-may-not-have-the-permissions-for-this)

Answer (score 2):

The permissions required for getting the joined teams is User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All. Please go through the [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams) for more information about the joined teams graph api call.

Comment: That's what my question is, I have already Given all the permissions in azure platform for Graph API and online exchange and passing below URL for auth code https://login.microsoftonline.com/********/oauth2/authorize?client_id=*************&response_mode=query&response_type=code&scope=openid+User.Read.All+User.Read.All+Group.Read.All+Group.ReadWrite.All&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient  Edited client id.Using auth code for access token and this access when I am using to call teams API I am getting error. I am calling API via postman.

Comment: @atiwari User.ReadWrite.All is missing. You have provided User.Read.All twice. Can you check it and try.